# Please always write time zone information in numeric format (e.g. GMT-X)

Tags: support, status-completed, notifications, timezone

Currently there is a global site message of

> There will be a short outage starting
>   at 12:30 Eastern time as we tune the
>   Database hardware

which completely fails to give me the intended information of when this actually is happening.

Just as I do not assume that you know that Norwegian `sommertid` equals GMT+2, you should not expect me to know that `Eastern time` equals GMT minus something.

Can you please always, always, **always** include some numeric information when referring to time zones?

Comment: Or even better, just use UTC like the rest of the site when making announcements

Comment: How many countries have an "Eastern" time zone?

Comment: At least two. Including Australia. @gab

Comment: I think Europe and Brazil also have Eastern times.

Comment: @Gabe: yes, [Eastern European Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_European_Time) (EET), UTC+2. There is a list at *[List of time zone abbreviations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations)*. Eastern Standard Time (EST), UTC-5 should be unique, in contrast to Eastern time.

Comment: And I'm just guessing that maybe Russia do too. @Gabe Brazil does have one, but it's highly overlooked as almost nobody lives there! :P

Comment: @Zypher (or anyone else) just wondering... Does it matter if this question is "solved" but no answers are given so it can be "marked" as such?